# Django templates inheritance

Tags: django, django-templates

For example:

base.html

```
<body>
    {% block content}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

base_index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    something
{% endblock %}

# add new block "for_child" to fill in with next inheritance
<h1>Name:
{% block for_child %}
{% endblock %}</h1>
```

base_index_child.html

```
{% extends 'base_index.html' %}

{% block for_child %}
    Peter
{% endblock %}
```

Result base_index_child.html:

```
<body>
    something
</body>
```

But i want (base.html -> base_index.html -> base_index_child.html)

```
<body>
    something
    <h1>Name: Peter</h1>
</body>
```

How to get this?

**Update (answer)**

Adding a block must be inside the block

base_index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    something

    <h1>Name:
    {% block for_child %} # block must be inside the block
    {% endblock %}</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563828/can-django-child-template-create-new-block-as-hook) is pretty much what you're asking.

So this would fix it:

base_index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    something

    <h1>Name:
    {% block for_child %}
    {% endblock %}
    </h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need.